Z3 slide puzzle
I am doing a slide puzzle for z3 solver in SMTlib.
Here is a link to the puzzle itself so you can have an idea of what is that:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle
The code below is how far I got, but I suppose there are problems with "movement", because I get unsat till the N 20(I have tested only till 20 timesteps). Help me resolve the issue. Also, a small reference picture:

Down below is my code so far:


(declare-fun F (Int Int Int) Int)
(declare-const N Int)
(declare-const S Int)

(assert
    (and
        (= N 10)
        (= S 3)
    )
)

(assert 
    (and
        (= (F 1 1 1) 8)
        (= (F 2 1 1) 7)
        (= (F 3 1 1) 6)
        (= (F 1 2 1) 5)
        (= (F 2 2 1) 4)
        (= (F 3 2 1) 3)
        (= (F 1 3 1) 2)
        (= (F 2 3 1) 1)
        (= (F 3 3 1) 0)
    )
)

(assert 
    (and
        (= (F 1 1 N) 1)
        (= (F 2 1 N) 2)
        (= (F 3 1 N) 3)
        (= (F 1 2 N) 4)
        (= (F 2 2 N) 5)
        (= (F 3 2 N) 6)
        (= (F 1 3 N) 7)
        (= (F 2 3 N) 8)
        (= (F 3 3 N) 0)
    )
)

(assert 
    (forall ((t Int))
        (implies
            (<= 1 t N)
            (distinct 
                (F 1 1 t)
                (F 2 1 t)
                (F 3 1 t)
                (F 1 2 t)
                (F 2 2 t)
                (F 3 2 t)
                (F 1 3 t)
                (F 2 3 t)
                (F 3 3 t)
            )
        )
    )
)

(assert 
    (forall ((x Int) (y Int) (t Int))
        (implies
            (<= 1 t N)
            (<= 1 x S)
            (<= 1 y S)
            (= (F x y t) 0)
            (or
                ; move up
                (and
                    (> y 1)
                    (= (F x (- y 1) (+ t 1)) 0)
                    (= (F x y (+ t 1)) (F x (- y 1) t))
                )
                ; move down
                (and
                    (< y 3)
                    (= (F x (+ y 1) (+ t 1)) 0)
                    (= (F x y (+ t 1)) (F x (+ y 1) t))
                )
                ; move left
                (and
                    (> x 1)
                    (= (F (- x 1) y (+ t 1)) 0)
                    (= (F x y (+ t 1)) (F (- x 1) y t))
                )
                ; move right
                (and
                    (< x 3)
                    (= (F (+ x 1) y (+ t 1)) 0)
                    (= (F x y (+ t 1)) (F (+ x 1) y t))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

(check-sat)
(get-model)



